# Joomla getting items via model wrong data type

Tags: joomla-3.7, model, array

I'm trying to retrieve articles from a particular category to display it as a part of some module located on the homepage. So I set states for model and retrieved the items via:

```
$items = $model->getItems();
```

then I did a var_dump:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {

  var_dump( $item );

}
```

And here is what I find strange (var_dump excerpt):

...

```
["images"]=> string(202) "{"image_intro":"images\/slider\/slider_02.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}" ["urls"]=> string(121) "{"urla":false,"urlatext":"","targeta":"","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}"
```

...

As you can see ["images"] or ["urls"] hold an array but the type is **string**! So I can't do $item->images->image_intro. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong or if it's normal? How can I get the value of image_intro in this case (only by using explode function?) or there is some line of code that I might forgot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a json encoded string.

```
$images = json_decode($item->images);
```

Comment: Thank you David! So is it normal or anything is wrong with my code so I get it like that?

Comment: Just the way it is stored in the db. In other application you will see serialized data, but json is not language specific. You code looks fine.